# Outputting a combination of different array values depending on what has been input

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I've created an android app that receives and reads in SMS messages.
 At the moment the application reads in the SMS and converts it to an array of 8 char's as it will only ever receive messages of 8 characters. for example the message might be "AbCdEfGh" which would be converted to [A][b][C][d][E][f][G][h].

```
if (array[0] == 'a'){
                this.abortBroadcast();
                Toast.makeText(context, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
            else if (array[0] == 'A'){
                //this.abortBroadcast();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
            else if (array[1] == 'b'){
                this.abortBroadcast();
                Toast.makeText(context, "b", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
            else if (array[1] == 'B'){
                this.abortBroadcast();
                Toast.makeText(context, "B", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
```

What I want the app to do is read each one of these chars and do something depending on if the character is uppercase or lowercase. For example if [0] equals 'a' then do something, else if [0] equals [A] then do something, and then move on and check the next element.
 I would like it to go through each element of the array and do something for each character in the message, currently the app will show "a" for 'a' and "A" for 'A' perfectly, the problem being that if you enter "ab" it will still only show "a" rather than "ab". it will only show the second letter if you enter the first one as blank, for example " b" will return "b".
 How should i arrange my code so that it selects and shows a combination of the arrays?? surely I do not have to just code each possible combination of the 8 characters that could be involved?? Could a switch statement be the solution? Would it be possible to implement some kind of loop so that once it has looked at the first array element, it loops round and looks at the next element?? Apologies if i have not explained this very clearly! hopefully someone with a bit more experience than me will be able to get their head round this problem. Thanks for any help

Comment: you are trying to match two characters at a time with one character, which is not possible, with your code,so when you enter 'ab' at [0] it will match a and will end , when you have " b" will match [1]=='b', are you getting it

Comment: yes this is correct. i would like it to carry on looking for another letter once it has decided whether [0] is 'A' or 'a'. so does [0] == 'a'? then do this and then carry on and do, does [1] == 'b'? then do this

Comment: so will i have to tell it what to do for each possible combination of 8 different characters? surely there is a way around this??

Comment: i think you can try nested switch cases, since its a combination problem

Comment: I thought a switch statement could be the solution but how would i go about doing it?

Comment: are you sure that you will have only a-z and A-Z chars? then only it would be feasible but would be tedius

Comment: combinations would be, 8 characters, A-H/a-h. so possible combinations could be..."aBCDEFGH" "Abcdefgh" "aBcDeFgH" "AbCdEfGh" etc.....

Comment: is this valid sequence "bcadefhg"? if yes then not possible with that permutations you are trying or will it always start with a/A and end with h/H with sorting order "abcdefgh"?

Comment: the order of the characters will always be "abcdefgh"

Comment: see my solution below and tell me if its working

Comment: @user2408578 would it be possible to implement some sort of loop?? so that it validates the first element of the array and instead of ending, it loops around and checks the next one??

Comment: see my edited version and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a semi colon at the end of your if else statement, then the code will carry on to the next if statement instead of stopping.

```
if (array[0] == 'a'){
        this.abortBroadcast();
        Toast.makeText(context, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.sendBroadcast(in);
    }
    else if (array[0] == 'A'){
        //this.abortBroadcast();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //context.sendBroadcast(in);
 //insert semi colon after } below:   
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not loop through your array, append the value of each array element to a string and then show the string at the end? Something like this:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == 'a'){
                this.abortBroadcast();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                sb.append("a");
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
                if(array[i+1] == 'b')
                {
                    //do whatever you want down here after finding a combination...
                }
            }
            else if (array[i] == 'A'){
                //this.abortBroadcast();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //sb.append("b");
                //context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
            //...
            //and so on...
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: this would still mean going through every possible combination of A-H, upper-lowercase wouldn't it?

Comment: Probably, yes. If you want to do a different action for every single combination, you are still going to have to code in 64 different actions which does sound quite tedious. Perhaps you can just do a check on the entire string instead of looping through each different combination.

Comment: it is going to be very tedious and just seems such a long winded way of doing it :/ the way i thought of it in my was: take an SMS string, convert it into an array of 8 characters, check the first element (is it upper or lower case), do something, move onto the next element

Comment: i'm sure there must be a way of doing this. validate array [0], do something, then validate array [1], do something, then validate array [2], do something.....and so on

Comment: Maybe build a list of "do somethings" and then handle that all at once after you've validated everything.

Comment: what about if it was to execute a line of code within the if statement that forces the next if statement to be carried out?? would that be possible?

Comment: You might be able to put the code in your `if` statements in separate methods and then just call the methods as you need them.

Comment: so put each if statement validating each element of the array into its own method and then call the methods at the top of the code. That seems like a very good idea to me!!!

Comment: i dont suppose you could advise me on how to do something like that??

Answer (score 0):

You use if-else statement in your code.
When array[0] equals a, it will not check the condition array[1] == 'B'.

```
       if (array[0] == 'a'){
            this.abortBroadcast();
            Toast.makeText(context, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            context.sendBroadcast(in);
        }
        else if (array[0] == 'A'){
            //this.abortBroadcast();
            //Toast.makeText(context, "A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //context.sendBroadcast(in);
        }
        if (array[1] == 'b'){
            this.abortBroadcast();
            Toast.makeText(context, "b", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            context.sendBroadcast(in);
        }
        else if (array[1] == 'B'){
            this.abortBroadcast();
            Toast.makeText(context, "B", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            context.sendBroadcast(in);
        }
```

Comment: yes so what would be another way of doing this/a way around it/a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

might will help,

```
Declare arr as String in your function and call this method as 
getArr(arr.charAt(0),arr);



getArr(char choice,arr)
{
   static int i=-1;
   i++;
   if(i>=arr.length())
     return;
   switch(choice)
   {
 case a:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
        this.abortBroadcast(); 
        Toast.makeText(context, arr.substring(0,i+1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
        context.sendBroadcast(in);
        //do above for all do something 
    break;
 case b:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case c:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case d:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case e:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case f:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case g:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case h:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case A:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case B:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case C:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case D:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case E:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case F:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case G:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
 case H:
    getArr(arr.charAt(i),arr);
    //do something
    break;
```

}
}

Comment: Call it as getArr(arr[0],arr);

Comment: Hi instead of //do something use this if you want   this.abortBroadcast();
Toast.makeText(context, arr.substring(0,i+1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.sendBroadcast(in);